# How to disable keychain completely in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, keychain, active-directory

Is there any way to completely disable keychain usage in Mavericks? We have a mac mini at work that we use in the conference room. The problem is that the keychain is not staying synced with Active Directory. Is there anyway to disable keychain popups?